# Iterate through XML list when parsing SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, nodes

I have this script which selects a value from an xml report. The report contains many of these values of the same name and I would like to select all the values in the list.

I know the number of items I need to iterate through

```
 ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'uri:website.co.uk/soap:examplenamespace')
 select top 100 report.value('(//report/paymentinfo/paymentdate)[1]', 'nvarchar(200)'), report
 from     
 [dbo].[reports]
```

There are 50 values i need to iterate through, not just the first 1 so something like

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'uri:website.co.uk/soap:examplenamespace')
 select top 100 report.value('(//report/paymentinfo/paymentdate)[1-50]', 'nvarchar(200)'), report
 from     
 [dbo].[reports]
```

Comment: Please poste your (reduced) XML. The solution will be somehow related to `CROSS APPLY` with `.nodes()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for providing the XML, now the answer is easy:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourReportTable(report XML);
INSERT INTO #YourReportTable VALUES
('<report>
     <accs>
        <acc>
          <paymentinfo>
            <paymentdate>2001-03-05</paymentdate>
            <amount>1200.00</amount>
          </paymentinfo>
        </acc>
        <acc>
          <paymentinfo>
            <paymentdate>2001-04-05</paymentdate>
            <amount>1200.00</amount>
          </paymentinfo>
        </acc>
        <acc>
          <paymentinfo>
            <paymentdate>2001-05-05</paymentdate>
            <amount>1200.00</amount>
          </paymentinfo>
        </acc>
    </accs>
  </report>');

 SELECT TOP 100 rep.value('(paymentdate)[1]', 'date') AS PaymentDate
               ,rep.value('(amount)[1]', 'decimal(10,4)') AS Amount
 FROM #YourReportTable AS repTbl
 CROSS APPLY repTbl.report.nodes('/report/accs/acc//paymentinfo') AS A(rep);
 GO

 DROP TABLE #YourReportTable;
```

The result

```
PaymentDate Amount
2001-03-05  1200.0000
2001-04-05  1200.0000
2001-05-05  1200.0000
```

Comment: Hey, thats work thanks! One more request, what if I want to bring the nulls if paymentdate is not in one of the records?

Comment: @mcorkers, just try my example and delete one paymentdate. This should appear as `NULL` in your result.

Comment: Is there a solution without the temporary table? As you assumed the report is contained in a column in the dbo

Comment: @mcorkers, just use the `SELECT` as it is, but replace the `#YourReportTable` with your actual table name, **but take away the `DROP TABLE` at the end!!!** to avoid data damage